# Java Load Web Page and Keep Track of Changes in HTML

Tags: java, html, selenium

I'm trying to load the web page `http://www.twitch.tv/NAME_OF_CHANNEL/chat?opentga=1` to keep track of a twitch chat through web scraping. The only problem is that whenever someone types a message in chat, a `ul` item is added to the html code. My question is, if I load the page with either Selenium or just an HTTP GET request, how can I keep getting the updated code so I can look out for all new chat messages that are sent into the chat?

This is what some of the code looks like.

[image]

As you can see there is a `ul` element that has a huge list of `div` elements with random ids. In each of the `div` elements there is the individual chat message, with certain information like what user sent it and at what time. The `div` elements are what keep getting updated, one being added every time a message is sent. How can I keep track of all the `div` elements saving each one in a list every time a message is sent? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can `poll` the DOM of your particular case. 
The meaning of `polling` is to set the driver in a monitor state where it waits for some condition to be fulfilled. 
You can have either `implicit` or `explicit` [waiting](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp#explicit-and-implicit-waits).

Something like this would be a good head start

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.get("http://www.twitch.tv/NAME_OF_CHANNEL/chat?opentga=1");

    WebDriverWait initialWait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 60);
    WebElement commentsContainer = initialWait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector("ul.chat-lines")));
    if(commentsContainer == null)
        throw new Exception("Page unresponsive!!!");

    int numberOfComments = commentsContainer.findElements(By.cssSelector("div[id^=ember]")).size() + 1;
    while(true) {
        String newCommentSelector = "chat-lines > div:nth-child(" + numberOfComments + ")";
        WebElement newComment = (new WebDriverWait(driver, 60))
          .until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.cssSelector(newCommentSelector)));
        if(newComment == null) continue;

        numberOfComments++;

        System.out.println(newComment.getText());
    }
}
```

This could be cleaned up. There might be errors, but the logic is straightforward.

You wait until you have the comments' container. Then you find all the comments present at that point and get their number. After that you just wait until you "see" the `initial_number_of_comments + 1` comment.

The selectors might not be correct. Feel free to change them at will. This is a never ending poll loop, so you might want to introduce some kind of exit logic here.

Comment: Thank you, I think this will work for what I'm doing! :D