# Chat message event for Youtube Live Streaming Api

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, chatbot, quota, youtube-livestreaming-api

I am currently working on a chat program that synchronizes live chats from several platforms including Youtube.
And it's working, also with Youtube, but there is one big problem: the quota limit of 10000 per day for the Youtube Data API v3.
There are two requests that are very important for this all to work.

1. LiveChatMessages list - costs 5 quota
2. LiveChatMessages insert - costs 20 quota

Obviously, it's important that messages written on Youtube need to be transmitted quickly to the other platforms so that viewers can interact well with each other.
That's why it's necessary to send a LiveChatMessage list request every 1 - 2 seconds.
Let's say every 2 seconds, then for a 150 minutes livestream it would need 22500 quota which is already much more than the limit allows.
But in addition there are also the messages of the other plattforms that need to be inserted to the youtube chat.
For example 400 messages, then it would cost 8000 quota and total 30500 quota.

I think it is clear that for a normal use the limit is way too low.
But I could solve this problem if I didn't have to send a list request every 2 seconds, but if my program always got a notification as soon as a message was sent by an event.
Is there such an event or do you know another solution to solve my problem?

I use java as a programming language.

And I know I could request more quota but in the request form they want to know stuff about your company and I don't have one, it is just a private project for myself.

Answer (score 0):

Okay I got a solution which helps a lot but only if you don't have too many messages:

Now I use selenium to track the youtube chat, it is an api you can use to open the normal chat popup of a youtube livestream (without actually see the browser being open / headless) and then check if new messages are available.

This doesn't cost quota but because Google hates free solutions you can't get information like the message id which is really important to delete the messages.
So everytime there is a new message I just send a LiveChatMessage List request that gives me all information I need.

In my question I explained that if you send a list request every 2 seconds for 150 minutes it would cost 22500 quota.
Now costs depend on the amount of message in the youtube chat.
In my question example I talked about 400 messages, that would be 2000 quota which is much better than 22500 quota.
I recommend that you don't send a list request if the messages comes from the bot which sends the messages from other platforms, then you save some quota.

I also thought about using other chatbots like Nightbot to insert chat messages.
The nightbot has a limit of 1 insert request per 5 seconds, which helps to use less quota, but it seems like you're not getting the message id in response, which might be important to have.

Here are 2 articles that helped me making this work:
[selenium-css-selectors](https://devqa.io/selenium-css-selectors/)
[Java Load Web Page and Keep Track of Changes in HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32444150/java-load-web-page-and-keep-track-of-changes-in-html)

Comment: Note that for YouTube Live Streaming API [LiveChatMessages: list](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/live/docs/liveChatMessages/list) endpoint, it is not mandatory to use Google OAuth 2.0, so you can also my [open-source](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/tree/9560baae896324e627301a0d459770e66915cc0a/noKey) no-key service at https://yt.lemnoslife.com for instance you can do in a quota free manner: https://yt.lemnoslife.com/noKey/liveChat/messages?part=snippet,authorDetails&liveChatId=YOUR_CHAT_ID

Comment: @BenjaminLoison does it make a difference in quota usage when I don't use OAuth 2.0 for this request?
Your no-key service looks cool but is this service reliable? Because this is really important to me, during a livestream I don't want to have any problems no matter how long I stream and on your website you say "I may add in the future limitation per IP etc if the quota need to be better shared among the persons using this API."

Comment: It doesn't make a difference in quota usage when using OAuth 2.0 or an API key. I can't promise that my service is reliable. You can have your own opinion on its reliability by having a look at [this issue](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/issues/18) and [its metrics](https://yt.lemnoslife.com/metrics/) since 8 September, 2022. The other solution would be to reverse-engineer the live chats instead of using Selenium but it's time-consuming to do this reverse-engineering.

Comment: @BenjaminLoison I will use your service because it helps even if the request amount is limited and if the limit is reached I try using my own api key and in addition I use my event solution, so that the risk of failure is as low as possible =) What is reverse-engineering?

Comment: For instance I solved [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/72223744) with [this reverse-engineering solution](https://github.com/Benjamin-Loison/YouTube-operational-API/commit/e0768177d69464a74eb4a8eb25be91c2d26ed707). To put it simply, I use the `Network` web-browser tab and try to understand how the web-browser interact with YouTube UI endpoints. That way I am able to retrieve YouTube UI content without running any *slow* JavaScript interpreter/graphical interface such as those in Selenium.